# Responding to touch in other classes

Tags: iphone

I'm building an iPhone app on top of the OpenGL template for the iPhone. I was about to add user interaction to the app when I noticed that it won't respond to touches in a few of my classes.

Currently, the `GameAppDelegate` calls my `EAGLView` class' `startAnimation` method, which eventually calls my `ES1Renderer` class' `render` method, which then finally calls my `Scene` `render` method. I know it's a bit of a mess at this point, but I'll clean it up eventually.

`-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` is only called and checked for in my `EAGLView` class. I don't know what I'm missing in the other classes (most importantly my `Scene` class) that will automatically check to see if I have that method and implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging just from the naming scheme, it sounds like `Scene` is not a `UIView`. The touch event method is called on whatever `UIView` is touched -- in this case, your `EAGLView`. If you'd like the `Scene` class to handle it, you can just call the method directly:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [myScene touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```